# CakePHP DebugKit ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

So, this is the second time I have seen this but cannot for the life of me explain why?!?

All of a sudden the DebugKit plugin stopped working and would not display in the browser. Looking at the console I can see the following:

**debug_kit/js/toolbar.js net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED**

So far I have tried rebooting laptop & server. Clearing cache/cookies in browser. Re-uploading the DebugKit plugin folder but still to no avail. Does anyone have any ideas what could be causing this? I have tried the good ol' "Google" approach

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

just make sure you don't have any extra line or space after `?>` in your modals, controllers and mainly on bootstrap ( I had a extra line one of my bootstraps's plugin).

or you can delete the `?>`, php will work fine.